# highlight function in android eclipse for android app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview

when I write a code like the following:

```
ListView employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

ListView type, and "list" should be highlight to different color.

But all I see is the "list" is highlighted. What can I do to make sure eclipse highligh all the keyword/type such as "ListView" keywork?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean changing the syntax coloring?

If it's that, go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring`, there you have lots of options to play with:

[image: Preferences menu]

Comment: Thanks, look likes there is no default option to highlight ListView. I was able to make that change as a custom one.